# MySQL incorrect result of insert

Tags: mysql

1. Created table 'testload' on demo database (int (15))
   http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/#PMAURL-2:sql.php?db=loadtest&table=testload&server=2&target=&token=b5d7382f24b478d22a2e7435d8f98a3b
2. Made 'INSERT INTO `testload` VALUES ('2212533532')'
3. Got value '2147483647' in 'testload' field.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

2147483647 is the maximum value of a signed 32 bit integer which corresponds to a MySQL INT.  2212533532 is larger than 2147483647 so it is being truncated at the maximum value.

Answer (score 3):

The value is bigger than the integer number you can put in to `int` field. The `int` in mysql is 4 bytes long so the maximum values are -2147483648 and 2147483647. You need to use `bigint` instead which is 8 bytes long. See mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks!
So, making this field 'unsigned' adds just 1 bit?
Urgently changing to bigint type.

When I've made int(15) I hoped that 15 will force MySQL to make appropriate field "capacity'...